# Java GSON parsing - Array and nested class

Tags: java, json, gson

I'm invoking a third party REST service for Job seeker details and it sends the   response back in JSON  format. The JSON data looks like

```
[
  {
   "Id": 1
  "County": "sample string 16",
  "Country": "sample string 17",
  "AtAddressSinceMonth": 1,
  "AtAddressSinceYear": 1,
  "AtAddressUntilMonth": 1,
  "AtAddressUntilYear": 1,
   "DateOfBirth": "2013-12-11T14:25:27.3753327-05:00",
   "Documents": [
      {
        "Type": "sample string 1",
        "Description": "sample string 2",
        "File": "sample string 3"
       },
      {
        "Type": "sample string 1",
        "Description": "sample string 2",
        "File": "sample string 3"
      },

    ],
    "Events": [
      {
        "StartDateTime": "2013-12-11T14:25:27.3753327-05:00",
        "EndDateTime": "2013-12-11T14:25:27.3753327-05:00",
        "Description": "sample string 3",
        "Attendees": [
          {
            "EmailAddress": "sample string 1",
            "FirstName": "sample string 2",
            "LastName": "sample string 3"
          },
          {
            "EmailAddress": "sample string 1",
            "FirstName": "sample string 2",
            "LastName": "sample string 3"
          }
        ]
       },
      {
        "StartDateTime": "2013-12-11T14:25:27.3753327-05:00",
        "EndDateTime": "2013-12-11T14:25:27.3753327-05:00",
        "Description": "sample string 3",
        "Attendees": [
          {
            "EmailAddress": "sample string 1",
            "FirstName": "sample string 2",
            "LastName": "sample string 3"
          },
      ....
      ....
  {
    "Id": 1,
   "County": "sample string 16",
    "Country": "sample string 17",
    "AtAddressSinceMonth": 1,
    "AtAddressSinceYear": 1,
   "AtAddressUntilMonth": 1,
   "AtAddressUntilYear": 1,
...
...

      }
     ]
   }
  ]
```

and it goes on like that..I've defincd a static class JobSeeker with all the variables and static inner class for all the nested variables..with respective set and get methods..

Also, created another class ArrayOfJobSeeker with the variable protected List jobSeeker;My class definition looks like

```
public class ArrayOfJobSeeker {

protected List<ArrayOfJobSeeker.JobSeeker> jobSeeker;

public List<ArrayOfJobSeeker.JobSeeker> getJobSeeker() {
    if (jobSeeker == null) {
        jobSeeker = new ArrayList<ArrayOfJobSeeker.JobSeeker>();
    }
    return this.jobSeeker;
}



public static class JobSeeker {


    protected String address;

    protected String atAddressSinceMonth;

    protected String atAddressSinceYear;
    protected String atAddressUntilMonth;
    protected String atAddressUntilYear;
    protected String city;
    protected String country;
    protected String county;
    protected XMLGregorianCalendar dateOfBirth;
    protected ArrayOfJobSeeker.JobSeeker.Documents documents;
    protected String emailAddress;
    protected ArrayOfJobSeeker.JobSeeker.Events events;
    protected String extension;
    protected String firstName;
    protected String genderCode;
    protected ArrayOfJobSeeker.JobSeeker.HistoryActivities historyActivities;
    protected String id;
    protected String lastName;
    protected String maidenName;
    protected String middleName;
```

and nested inner classes

```
    public static class Documents {


        protected List<ArrayOfJobSeeker.JobSeeker.Documents.Document> document;
        public List<ArrayOfJobSeeker.JobSeeker.Documents.Document> getDocument() {
            if (document == null) {
                document = new ArrayList<ArrayOfJobSeeker.JobSeeker.Documents.Document>();
            }
            return this.document;
        }              

          public static class Document {

            protected String description;
            protected String file;
            protected String type;
       }  //end Document
   } // end Documents
```

}//end jobseeker

I'm quite not sure how to parse this nested array with GSON as this code throws error

```
File file = new File("c:/temp/testJSON.txt"); 
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
Gson gson = new Gson();   
gson.fromJson(br, ArrayOfJobSeeker.class)
```

Please help.

Thanks

Comment: What is the error? One method I have found effective in such cases is to create the data structure in memory and marshal it to a string (in this case using `toJson()`), save to a file and compare that with the text you are trying to parse

Comment: `static` inner classes are no different than top level classes when it comes to serialization and deserialization.

Comment: I had problems creating my own Java classes based on JSON, but I found this [json gen tool](http://jsongen.byingtondesign.com/) to be really helpful

Comment: <<static inner classes are no different than top level classes when it comes to serialization and deserialization. –  Sotirios Delimanolis>>  - Can't I use inner static class? Please elaborate

Comment: Does it have to be Gson? Have you considered anything else?

Comment: It need ot be Gson..please suggest working solution for any other approaches..thx

Comment: With the below code, it prints the whole json string value File file = new File("c:/temp/testJSON.txt"); 
      BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file)); 
      Gson gson = new Gson();   

      JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
      JsonArray Jarray = parser.parse(br).getAsJsonArray();System.out.print(Jarray.get(0).getAsJsonObject());   --- just wondering how to loop this further.. pls help

Comment: Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself.

Answer (score 1):

The issue with blindly deserializing arbitrary json into strongly-typed class structures is it's too fragile; a single misplaced type and KABOOM!

Here's what I'd do. You're using Java, so throw some groovy into the mix:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper;
...
JsonSlurper jsonParser = new JsonSlurper();
List<Map> jsonMap = (List<Map>)jsonParser.parse(new FileReader( jsonFile));
```

JsonSlurper parses the json into a list of hierarchical HashMaps, each containing arrays and primitive wrappers (Long, Boolean, etc) where necessary; you don't create custom classes in advance, just parse raw json; done.

You can use `jsonMap` 'as is" (that's what I'd do). Or, if you insist on creating your own class to store all the data with getters and setters, explore `jsonMap` with your debugger, traverse the object to see the types, then you'll know exactly what types are necessary for whatever class you want to implement. The only downside with JsonSlurper, compare to Gson, it will not deserialize into a custom class like Gson; you need to do that part yourself.

PS: If your json starts/ends with `[]`, `jsonParser` returns `List<Map>`, if it starts/ends with `{}`, it returns `HashMap<String,Object>` as the enclosing object.

Answer (score 1):

Referring your comment in the question, does your code really print the whole json string? I think you would only get the first element.
If it's possible, I suggest you pull out the inner classes, and do something like

```
JsonArray jarray = new JsonParser().parse(json).getAsJsonArray();
for (JsonElement e : jarray) {
    JsonObject jobSeeker = e.getAsJsonObject();

    JsonArray events = e.get("Events").getAsJsonArray();
    JsonArray documents = e.get("Documents").getAsJsonArray();
    // iterate the array, deserialize the objects and do your work

    jobSeeker.remove("Events");
    jobSeeker.remove("Documents");
    // deal with the job seeker;
}
```

This doesn't seem to be a good approach, but I think it should work.